# Regex Expression for not accepting a single underscore but accepts single alphabet

Tags: regex

The expression should not accept any special characters except an underscore and no numbers in it and it should accept single or more alphabets.
Examples

abc_dc (Should be accepted)

_bsc (Should be accepted)

A (Should be accepted)

_ (Should not be accepted)

a__b (should not be accepted)

I have tried:

```
(^(?!.*?[_]{2})[^_][a-zA-Z_]+$)
```

but this does not accept single alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following pattern:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=[a-zA-Z_]+$)(?!.*_{2,}).+
```

Pattern explanation:

Generally, multiple validations are being achieved by placing lookaheads at beginning of a pattern, I used the same strategy.

Explanation:

`^` - anchor - match beginning of a string

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` - positive lookahead - assert that what follows current position is zero or more any characters (`.*`) followed by alphabet character. Simply - assert that what follows contains at least one letter.

`(?=[a-zA-Z_]+$)` - assert what follows contains only letters or underscore until end of string (thanks to `$`).

`(?!.*_{2,})` - negative lookahead - assert what follows DOES NOT contain two (or more) following underscores (thanks to `_{2,}`

`.+` - match on or more of any characters.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d4d8Dq/1)

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

```
(^(?!.*?[_]{2})[_]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z_]*$)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use:

```
^_?(?:[a-zA-Z]+_?)+$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/T3q7M5/1)

---

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `_?` - An optional hyphen.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `[a-zA-Z]+_?` -Match 1+ alphachars and an optional hyphen.
  - `)*` - Close non-capture group and match 1+ times.
- `$` - End line anchor.

**Note:** This would also allow for trailing hyphens, e.g: '_a_', 'a_' and '_a_b_'. If you don't want to allow a trailing hyphen, try `^(?:_?[a-zA-Z]+)+$` instead.